# Transfer large files using HTTP/POST

Tags: c, http, post, webkit, gecko

How can I upload (very) large file with HTTP protocol in C (or C++)?

I know it's not the right way to upload huge files, but that's not the point.

I've already seen sources about POST transfers of files in C++ but I noticed that, each time, the WHOLE binary file was included inside the POST sequence (between "--boundary").

So, before going deeper and deeper into Webkit/Gecko source code, does somebody know how do they do?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about downloading? `POST` request sounds more like an upload.

Comment: Yes of course... I change my question, my fault :(

Comment: You could use HTTP PUT with Content-Range, to be flexible if the transmission breaks up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use "Content-Range" header in HTTP POST request, to upload a slice of a huge file.

```
POST http://[server_ip]:80/upload?fn=xx.dat HTTP/1.1
Content-Range: bytes=0-4095
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 4096

......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chunking method to send the data in chunks. This will allow you to send/receive data on a larger scale. Refer to RFC 2616 on how chunking really works.