# Effectively caching data uploads in Android

Tags: android

I have implemented a queue service in Android that will change states based on queue and wifi/data connectivity events.

I queue transactions to be posted to a remote url.  If the device has a data or wifi connection, it will iterate the queue and post data to the url until the queue is empty, or there is a disconnect event.

I can login to my app, enable airplane mode, generate data, turn airplane mode off, and the transaction are posted.  No slow down, even with thousands of transactions.  (I was trying to pish it a bit)

Enter: low reception!
My app slows down enormously when the 3G reception is low. (Yes, all uploading happens off the ui thread.)  It seems that the cause of this slow down has to do with the post to the server taking a very long time to happen and sometimes just failing.

My question is, how can I solve this?  Check for signal quality?  Poll a known address?  How do other apps, such as Gmail solve this?  This must be a common scenario!

Comment: You certainly need to have a plan for cases like "connectivity is there, but the server is slow, unreachable etC" Two ideas: 1. persist the cache, define a maximum size that you are fine with (meaning: when it's full you don't care if events are thrown away). 2. Measure the time one request takes. If the time is larger than the time it takes to generate events, pause longer to take load of the connection or the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you could potentially have thousands of tasks that all need to be executed, then surely they should be managed. Have you thought about implementing your own [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)? The documentation is very good and the class is easy to understand, but if you need examples try these sites:

- http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/ThreadPoolExecutor.shtml
- http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/threadpoolexecutor-basics/

The benefit of this is that you can limit the maximum number of threads you are spawning, so you shouldn't get a system-wide slow down if you limit your thread count to a reasonable number (For Android I'd recommend no more than 20).

Comment: I am not executing the uploads in parallel.  At one time, there is only one upload happening.  Yes, the upload queue is in a separate process from the "main" application, but, uploading still only happens one at a time.  Am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: If you're only executing one task at a time, and the task is ran in the background, why is it slowing your UI? Or is that the million dollar question? :)

Answer (score 0):

May be do some fine-tuning of socket and conenction timeout? Thus, if your connection is slow and stalled, timeout will occur and transmission will fail.

After connection/sending is failed you can retry transmission later or do something else.

To adjust timeouts you can use the following code:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30 * 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15 * 1000);

HttpClient client =  DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
// use client...
```

Answer (score 0):

We have similar situation for our application. We have considered signal issues to be a reality and one that can happen any time. One of the point that we follow is not to remove any content from device unless we get a functional confirmation from server and just base on http status code.As in the slow network or the cases where we can lose signal suddenly, while we may have posted our content, there were many cases where data was received only partially. And so we decided to let server know device by some manner [result through some http get based request calls made by device] that content has been received. 
More than performance or checking the network, the question that you asked, we needed such behavior for our application robustness.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out using HTTP Range headers, for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927219/transfer-large-files-using-http-post).

The server should write payload to disk while reading, and handle disconnects. The client cannot know how many bytes payload actually reached the server, so it needs to sync up with the server every time there has been a network error. Dont forget to handle battery and user issues too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for a better signal, perhaps the [SignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) class, with its getCdmaDbm, getEvdoDbm, and getGsmSignalStrength methods, is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM#!

advanced coding tips and tricks, bandwidth-saving techniques, implementation patterns, exposure to some of the lesser-known API features, and insight into how to minimize battery drain by ensuring your app is a good citizen on the carrier network.